# Amazon EBS - extend LVM partition (non destructively)

Tags: partition, lvm, amazon-ec2, xfs, resize2fs

I have an Amazon EBS volume that I'm using as a backing store for MongoDB, and I want to extend it.

The volume holds a single partition, which is an LVM partition type. That partition belongs to a single physical volume, which belongs to a single volume group, which exposes a single logical volume, which is formatted to the XFS filesystem.

I extend the volume in AWS successfully, but I cannot find any instructions online on how to resize a partition in linux **non-destructively**.

pvresize does not work

lvextend does not work

What do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Partitions are P.I.T.A. But you can create new partition, and do `vgextend $VG $NEWPARTITION`.

This has a caveat of course: partitions on single disk are treated as separate devices, so LVM might create a mirror/RAID1 on two partitions.

But as you are on Amazon EBS, I assume you are not using RAIDs (EBS does keep data safe for you, and handles snapshots). And you plan to use the entire partition for LV, so you are safe.